# this is a python telegram bot code, it should do a poll, like the one in the photo

Tags: python, bots

this is the code of a telegram bot in python, it should make polls, as in the photo, and should not be anonymous when someone wrote the command '/calling<here time{20:00 or 16:00, etc.}>',[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veBPs.jpg)c.}>'

```
import telebot
import config
import time
import math
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher , executor, types


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["сalling"])
def сalling(message):
    mess = f"<b>{"message"}</b>"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess,parse_mode="html")

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.